# discord.js updated, I don't understand the new ReactionCollector

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

Heyo!

Discord.js has updated recently and I do not understand the new **reactioncollector** system and that's why I need your help !

So, here is my code:

```js
msg.edit(e).then(async function(AttenteDeleteMessage){
                    await AttenteDeleteMessage.react("✅")
                    await AttenteDeleteMessage.react("❌")
                    const filter = (reaction, user) => (reaction.emoji.name === '✅'||reaction.emoji.name === '❌') && user.id==message.author.id
                    var Collection = await AttenteDeleteMessage.awaitReactions(filter, { max:1,time: 300000 })
                    var TempsEcoule = false
                    console.log("Collection")
                    if (Collection.get("✅") && Collection.get("✅").users.size >= 2){
                      AttenteDeleteMessage.edit("Approving...")
                      file.push({user: infos.player, reason: infos.reason, approvedBy: message.author.id})
                      wait.shift()
                      AttenteDeleteMessage.edit("Request sucessfully approved !")
                      fs.writeFile("./waiting.json", JSON.stringify(wait), (err) => {if (err) console.error(err)})
                      fs.writeFile("./blacklist.json", JSON.stringify(file), (err) => {if (err) console.error(err)})
                    }else{
        if (Collection.get("❌") && Collection.get("❌").users.size >= 2){
          AttenteDeleteMessage.edit("Request denied.")
          wait.shift()
          fs.writeFile("./waiting.json", JSON.stringify(wait), (err) => {if (err) console.error(err)})
        }else{
          AttenteDeleteMessage.edit("You've took too long to answer.")
          console.log()
        }
                    }
      })
```

Maybe somebody can help me!

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: Well, it won't work and when I click the reaction, it edits the message by "You've took too long to answer".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the answer! Here it is:

```
msg.edit("_ _",e).then(async function(AttenteDeleteMessage){
                    await AttenteDeleteMessage.react("✅")
                    await AttenteDeleteMessage.react("❌")
                    const filter = (reaction, user) => (reaction.emoji.name === '✅'||reaction.emoji.name === '❌') && user.id==message.author.id
                    var Collection = AttenteDeleteMessage.createReactionCollector(filter, { max:1,time: 300000 })
                    var TempsEcoule = false
                    console.log("Collection")
                    Collection.on('collect', (reaction, reactionCollector) => {
                        if (reaction.emoji.name == "✅") {
                            AttenteDeleteMessage.edit("Approbation en cours...")
                      file.push({user: infos.player, reason: infos.reason, approvedBy: message.author.id})
                      wait.shift()
                      AttenteDeleteMessage.edit("La demande a été approuvée avec succès !")
                      fs.writeFile("./waiting.json", JSON.stringify(wait), (err) => {if (err) console.error(err)})
                      fs.writeFile("./blacklist.json", JSON.stringify(file), (err) => {if (err) console.error(err)})
                        } else if (reaction.emoji.name == "❌") {
                            AttenteDeleteMessage.edit("La demande a bien été refusée")
          wait.shift()
          fs.writeFile("./waiting.json", JSON.stringify(wait), (err) => {if (err) console.error(err)})
                        }
})
```

(Ik, the code is in french)

Sorry for disturbing... Have a nice day, and happy coding!